# How to get CachedRowSet implementation by Sun in my Java project?

Tags: java, eclipse, cachedrowset

I have created a Java Project in Eclipse. My JDK is 1.6.0_34. I want to use the implementation of `javax.sql.rowset.CachedRowSet` interface in one of my class. I know Sun/Oracle wrote its implementation as `CachedRowSetImpl` and it should be part of JDK. But I am not getting it. This is my code:

```
CachedRowSet cachedRowSet = new CachedRowSetImpl();
```

This is the error message Eclipse is giving me:

> CachedRowSetImpl cannot be resolved to a type

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: do you have `import com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl;` ?

Comment: When I type in `import com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl;` I got this error **Access restriction: The type CachedRowSetImpl is not accessible due to restriction on required library C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\rt.jar**

Comment: http://www.coderanch.com/t/540789/JDBC/databases/troubles-importing-CachedRowSetImpl

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to change the eclipse _Forbidden reference (access rules)_ from error to warning. So instead I configure the build path: first remove the JRE and then add it back. And it is working now! Damn. A bug in Eclipse?